# Loop for random string

Tags: php, mysql, loops, random

```
$new_random_string = substr(str_shuffle('0123456789'), 0, 2);

$strings = mysql_query("SELECT `string` FROM `table`");
while ($string = mysql_fetch_row($strings)) {

if ($new_random_string == $string[0]) 

// generate new random string

}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`string`) VALUES ('".$new_random_string."')");
```

I want a loop to generate a new string in case it already exists in database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function gen_string() {
   return substr(str_shuffle('0123456789'), 0, 2);
}

do {
$rand = gen_string();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as rows FROM `table` where `string` ='".$rand ."'; ");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);

} while ($row['rows']>0);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`string`) VALUES ('".$rand."')");
```

It is not tested but it should work.

Comment: p.s. Make sure the gen_string has the ability to generate more than enough random strings you need, because if all the random string gets inserted in the table. You will have an infinite loop. length of 2 looks very small.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to generate random strings and insert them into the database, but with the restriction that there cannot be duplicates.

To ensure there cannot be duplicates the best approach is to [create a UNIQUE index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) on that column. Then the database will ensure that there will never be a duplicate value.

To insert new values you can either query the database to see if your specific string exists already before inserting it. Or you can just go ahead and try to insert and see if it works - the UNIQUE constraint will prevent any duplicates from being inserted.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(1)
{
   // generate new random string
   if(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `string` ".$new_random_string), 0) == 0){
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`string`) VALUES ('".$new_random_string."')");
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
do{

    $new_random_string = substr(str_shuffle('0123456789'), 0, 2);
    $string = mysql_query("SELECT `string` FROM `table` WHERE `string` = $new_random_string");
    $string = mysql_fetch_row($strings)

}while($new_random_string == $string[0]);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`string`) VALUES ('".$new_random_string."')");
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to my question. I solved the problem :)